# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPrimaryDisplay' of undefined (screen.getPrimaryDisplay())

Tags: javascript, electron, screen, screenshot

I'm trying to get screen size using this. It's working fine on the previous version. Failed to work on electron 6.0.0

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
const {desktopCapturer, screen} = require('electron');

var mainScreen = screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
var dimensions = mainScreen.size;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access a Main process module like `screen` from a Renderer process you must use the `remote` module.

```
const {remote, desktopCapturer} = require('electron'); // Renderer process modules
const {screen} = remote; // Main process modules
```